# How I get the name of the taxonomy term reference of the content type

Tags: entities

I created a content type. One of the field of the content type is entity term reference. Now I want to fetch the term of the particular content type and load the nodes that contain the term.I used the following code. But does not get the answer. Any error in my concept?

```
$aupl_node_query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$aupl_referrence = $aupl_node_query
->entityCondition('entity_type',  'taxonomy_term')
->execute();
dpm($aupl_referrence);
$aupl_node = node_load_multiple(array(), $aupl_referrence, true);
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found the answer correct. So, that people can re use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) having detailed information about entity queries.

You should use `->entityCondition('entity_type',  'node')`  rather than using `->entityCondition('entity_type',  'taxonomy_term')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add condition by taxonomy term ID in your query

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('YOUR_FIELD_REFERENCE_NAME', 'tid', $YOUR_TAXONOMY_TERM_ID);
$query = $query->execute();
```